# PostgreSQL: VACUUM FULL or CLUSTER?

Tags: postgresql

I'm nearly out of disk space because of a query that tried to update every row in a huge table. I don't have enough space for `CLUSTER` (though it would barely fit if I dropped indexes first and recreated them afterwards).

How can I estimate how long `VACUUM` will take? How about `VACUUM FULL`? How do the three (with `CLUSTER`) compare in terms of running time and disk usage?

It's PostgreSQL 8.3.

Comment: For whats it worth, `VACUUM` is not going to reclaim the space. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html (search "reclaim"). There is no difference in terms of disk space you will need to re-create the table: both `VACUUM FULL` and `CLUSTER` will need to make a full copy. If you indeed have a mega large table, you should be using partitioning (see TimescaleDB). Then you could vacuum each partition individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use cluster, until 8.4 vacuum full is broke. if it takes to long you might as well dump and reload the table.

Comment: How can I estimate how long `VACUUM` takes and what drawbacks does it have compared to `CLUSTER`? It seems like `CLUSTER` wins whenever you can afford it and lock the table, because when it finishes it leaves it in optimal state.